# MVC Routing - Using NGINX to route instead of PHP (or Ruby, etc.)

Tags: model-view-controller, nginx, php

I'm currently messing around with making a custom MVC framework for educational (and, if it's good, actual practical) use, and I like to investigate different scenarios for possible performance boosts.

When it comes to URI routing, I'm familiar with the standard URI format of

```
/controller/action/id
```

And parsing the data out of this to control the routing wouldn't be too difficult. Now, what I'm moreso wondering about is the performance difference between having nginx parse this URI string out into a query string of some type to pass to a controller directly, so that would end up like

```
/foo/bar/12 => /application/foo.php?action=bar&id=12
```

instead of

```
/foo/bar/12 => /index.php?controller=foo&action=bar&id=12
```

or even

```
/foo/bar/12 => /index.php?uri=/foo/bar/12   (note that this would be encoded)
```

I'm aware that nginx passes the url, query string, and other things to php-fpm in other variables already, but this is just for illustrative purposes to show what I'm thinking.

Is this a stupid thing to do? I know that by defining routes explicitly in nginx would mean me needing to restart nginx every time I alter the routes in the config, which could be a downside.

So, to restate the question: When it comes to MVC routing, is there any worthwhile performance gain by having the actual webserver (in this case, nginx) itself handle the routing to the controller OR is using a standard landing script (like index.php in the root of the directory) and passing along the URI to be parsed for routing perfectly fine?

Thanks ahead of time. Also, I'm just learning about these things, so I wholeheartedly welcome suggestions on what I should be doing instead.

Comment: here is a thought-experiment: how would you use your framework, to implement a bi-lingual news site, where URL is semi-translated too ?

Comment: You bring up a good question, as I haven't considered that yet. If I were to be considering other languages, I would probably have an extra directive added to the uri at the very end (such as /en, /es, etc) and have a map that can properly localize the uri to something my framework can understand and use to properly query the database. This is all off the top of my head, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't mix application logic (URL routing) into your HTTP server. Lots of PHP apps used to rely on Apache .htaccess files for this sort of thing.  It ends up being a mess.

As you mention, it would require restarting Nginx to change routes, and it would also tie your application to Nginx, unless you wanted to rewrite all your rules for another HTTP server at some future date. Even worse, if you decide to scale your app out over more than one server, you'll have to repeat these rules for each upstream.

tl;dr Keep your layers separate.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but still was curious. Thanks a lot!